# Template not rendered from controller drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have trouble rendering a template from a controller in a custom Drupal 8 module.

I am calling this controller method :

```
  public function displayEngineUI() {
$build['#theme'] = 'bretagnecom-search-engine';

return $build;}
```

There is no problem reaching controller, i can var_dump inside. But the content of the template is not rendered.

My module file structure look like this :

bretagnecom_search_engine.module    src

./src:
Controller

./src/Controller:
DefaultController.php

./templates:
bretagnecom-search-engine.html.twig

Any idea about what i'm doing wrong? I usually render a few html directly from controller with inline-template but i would like to isolate my html in his template file this time.

Thank's for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess template is not defined in hook_theme().

First just change hyphens to underscores:

```
public function displayEngineUI() {
  $build['#theme'] = 'bretagnecom_search_engine';
  return $build;
}
```

and in bretagnecom_search_engine.module add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function bretagnecom_search_engine_theme() {
$themes = [
  'bretagnecom_search_engine' => [
    'variables' => [
      'your_custom_variable_1' => NULL,
      'your_custom_variable_2' => NULL
  ]
];
```

If you do not have variables, just remove that part of code.

You can find more info here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module